# sql update a field with itself and extra string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a field with the contents of itself an added string but it does not work

```
UPDATE Products_Joined SET Products_Joined.TechSpecs = Products_Joined.TechSpecs + 'test'
```

Any ideas

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Is it running but just not changing the value?

Comment: It gives an error. This is a e-commerce platform which allows you to run SQL query's to update the product database. Unfortunately it does not tell you the particular error. Data type is text.

Comment: Hrm.  So it quite literally just says "Error" without any details... that is a difficult one to debug.  The statement you supplied IS valid SQL.  It is possible this platform is interpreting the statement before it gets to the SQL server and declaring the error itself.  Is this a custom e-commerce platform or is it a product with a name so we can look more into it perhaps?

Comment: So I was looking at the volusion boards and I saw this
http://support.volusion.com/article/why-do-i-get-error-invalid-sql-statement-expected-delete-insert-procedure-select-or-update

In this case it gives an error message, even though it's relatively unsophisticated.  Does yours not even give you that?  It seems like this is just some limit it's putting on you.

Comment: Nope, I do not get that or similar response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Data type is text

If you are on SQL Server 2005 or higher you can cast your `text` column to `varchar(max)`.

```
UPDATE Products_Joined 
SET TechSpecs = ISNULL(CAST(TechSpecs AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '') + 'test'
```

Comment: Hmm, This works if there is already something in the field but will not add the 'test' if the field is null. It doesn't return an error. Any idea why it will not add the 'test' with nothing in the field?

Comment: @user357034 - You can use `isnull` to handle the case when there are null values in `TechSpecs`.

Answer (score 2):

that should work, but you might need to remove the table name

```
UPDATE Products_Joined SET TechSpecs = TechSpecs + 'test'
```

Comment: I tried that as well and several combination of it. Basically anything that I could think of I tried. If I try and add another field it works fine, just cannot add to itself.

Comment: Wait so you CAN say like `update Products_Joined set TechSpecs = NonTechSpecs + 'hello'` ?

Comment: yes obviously that is not a correct name but if it was then yes I can do that with no problem

Comment: Sure it was just for illustrative purposes.  What if you set up a new column that is completely empty .  Try a statement like `update Products_Joined set TechSpecs = [Empty Column] + TechSpecs + 'test'`
point being perhaps you can fool it into letting you concatenate the values if you put some other column name in there even if it is empty.

Comment: They don't allow us to do that as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join two string in SQL use CONCAT as CONCAT (string1,string2) 
an example:

`UPDATE Products_Joined 
SET TechSpecs = CONCAT (TechSpecs ,'test') ;`

Answer (score 0):

Since the column data type is text you cannot do a concatenation  with a string since the column TexhSpecs is binary data type(TEXT) .

Comment: Hope this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx) might help you .